# OSM offline on Android

Tags: android, openstreetmap, offline, osmdroid

I'm trying to build an offline map on android and I'm still a beginner in that. so I added osmdroid to my project and I downloaded a the map data from this [link](http://download.geofabrik.de/). after some searching in the internet I still didn't find an example to display the data. In addition osmdroid use sd card location from what I found. is there a possibility to change that with a clear example about how to do it ?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You downloaded raw openstreetmap data. Osmdroid requires rendered tiles for offline functionality.

So you have two problems:

1) How to get rendered tiles.
2) How to integrate them into the application for offline usage.

Osmdroid has quite good documentation about offline maps and it is quite complex topic which cannot be covered in one proper Stackoverflow answer. You'll need to go through [osmdroid wiki article Offline-Map-Tiles](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/Offline-Map-Tiles) where are covered both your problems (and even your question about file location).

There are other wiki topics you schuld check.

- https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/Map-Sources
- https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/Modular-Tile-Provider-Architecture

Comment: thank you for your answer ! for the first question id it ok if I use mobile atlas creator to get tiles and does it work with osmdroid ?

Comment: for the second I checked the link you post and I did the same steps and i used the sdcard location but the map didn't appear in my mapview !

Comment: @chogath They are mentioning mobile atlas creator on the wiki so I guess it should work, I have never tried it myself though. For sdcard -> create another question with mcve ( https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ) and we can try to find the problem. Generally this question is too broad for stackoverflow and you should try more things and ask separate questions for separate problems.