# How do I use an .osm file with the osmdroid library?

Tags: android, dictionary, osmdroid

I am creating an offline map application using osmdroid. I have downloaded a complete map of my country in the form of `<country>.osm.bz2` from [here](http://download.geofabrik.de/asia.html). This zip file weighs about 170 MB and when unzipped, it becomes a 2.3 GB xml file. How can I use this file in my application. Can I use it in bz2 format or should I extract it first?
There is a similar question on StackOverflow, but it does not state which map format they want to work with offline.
I didn't find anything on how to use osm or osm.bz2 files specifically.

Comment: Hi, this was alerady ansewered on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45792284/osm-offline-on-android/45793981#45793981

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OSM offline on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45792284/osm-offline-on-android)

Answer (score 1):

osmdroid does not support the .osm format. You can use mapsforge, assuming conversion from the .osm format into their format which would give you the desired effect.

Comment: Is mapsforge a library that I should add to my project and work with instead of osmdroid?

Comment: either or. osmdroid provides an adapter to use mapsforge for an on the fly offline tile provider with the rest of osmdroid's overlay support. Mapsforge proper is a complete map engine so it can be used by itself too